# Reading mailbox file in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x

Here I was trying to read some mailbox file but in ret

```
def readFiles(path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            inBody = False
            lines = []
            f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
            for line in f:
                if inBody:
                    lines.append(line)
                elif line == '\n':
                    inBody = True
            f.close()
            message = '\n'.join(lines)
            yield path, message
```

Here is  the path  format I use.I also tried removing html from here.

```
    readFiles('/emails/spam/*.html')
```